# Can't use wifi after installing kali linux dual boot

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I recently installed kali linux alongside windows (dual boot).But the problem is i cant use wifi.
***Ifconfig*** shows only "***lo***" interface while ***iwconfig*** shows ***wlan0***(which doesn't work in windows) and ***wlan1*** (my usb wireless card which works on windows and kali linux in live mode).
But the problem is both of them aren't mentioned in ifconfig and are only mentioned in iwconfig. Whenever i try to click select networks a window opens turn on wifi.
I have also edited networkconfigration file where i put true instead of false. 
Clicking on turn on wifi does nothing. I dont have access to lan network so cant run apt-get upgrade.
Please help me.

Comment: And "ifconfig wlan0 up" does?

Comment: Is rf-kill running?

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem but I was using an external wifi card. You can get them pretty cheap for like 2 bucks. I started to work when I removed that and reattached again. Maybe you can do that to your internal cards to get it to work properly